# Video not playing inside bootstrap modal in chrome browser

Tags: jquery, html, spring

I made simple logic based on the Database path from video should loaded into the bootstrap modal.

Jquery

```
var video_path = $("#video_path").val()+data.video_name;
$("#video1").attr('src',video_path);
```

HTML

```
<video width="400" autoplay controls>
    <source id="video1" type="video/mp4" >
</video>
```

BootStrap  Modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModa3" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">View Courses</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="box box-warning">
                    <div class="box-header">
                    </div><!-- /.box-header -->
                    <div class="box-body">
```

Answer (score 1):

I think i have the solution.
see if this helps you.

```css
.modal-body{
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<body>
    <!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Open Button
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <video width="90%" controls>
          <source src="video_path" type="video/mp4">
            Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
        </video>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: the  video URL src added to the within video tag ,but my problem is video keep on buffering

Answer (score 0):

Updating the answer for 2022 ... autoplay must also have muted attribute in order to work.

```
<video width="400" autoplay muted controls>
    <source id="video1" type="video/mp4" >
</video>
```